# Wait for remote Powershell script to finish

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a powershell script to import Dynamics NAV Application Objects to my Dynamics NAV 2018 database.
Microsoft is providing a PS cmdlet - [Import-NAVApplicationObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.dynamics.nav.ide/import-navapplicationobject?view=dynamicsnav-ps-2018) - to do so, but I have trouble to wait for the command to finish.

I have a calling script which does the following

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $TargetMachine -Credential $MyCredential
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ArgumentList $Database_Name_user, $MyCredential -ScriptBlock {
    $process = Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList "-File `"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Database\Import1.ps1`" $args[0]"
    $process.WaitForExit()
    if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        throw $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    }
}
```

The script `Import1.ps1` on my `$TargetMachine` looks like this

```
param(
[String]$Database_Name_user
)

try {
    $AllFiles = "C:\Users\User\Documents\AllFiles.txt"

    $Modules = "C:\GIT\Loading Components\NAVModuleImport.ps1" 
    $OutputBuffer = import-module $Modules

    Import-NAVApplicationObject -Path $AllFiles -DatabaseServer "SQLSRV001" -DatabaseName $Database_Name_user -SynchronizeSchemaChanges "No" -ImportAction "Overwrite" -Confirm:$false | Out-Null

}
catch{
    $_ | Out-File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Import1.txt"
}
```

The file `AllFiles.txt` has a size of 220 MB and contains more than 7700 Dynamics NAV Application Objects (tables, pages, codeunits and so on). 
When I launch the script which executes `Import-NAVApplicationObject` directly from the remote computer stored in `$TargetMachine` everything works smootly and the process takes up to 10 to 15 minutes, as expected.

When calling the script as shown in the first code example the output stops for a minute and then says everything is done.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

**Edit: Solution**

I noticed that my scripts as shown are working, the `Import-NAVApplicationObjects` cmdlet just failed.
When I elevate the powershell process on the remote computer and run the import, the cmdlet tried to authenticate as NT-Authority\Anonymous to the database.
Then I passed the credentials of the user that opens the remote PSSession to `Import1.ps1` and used the parameters `-UserName` and `-Password` of the import cmdlet.
Sadly this process failed *again*.

Now I tried some things with the user I want to use for authenticating, changing passwords etc and it worked! The password contained a semicolon `;` and apparently the import cmdlet was not happy with that.

So my simple solution is: Removing the semicolon from the password.

Comment: You cannot use `Powershell_ISE` to run scripts like you try in your code in the `Start-Process`. The ISE is only for development. To run a script you have to use a normal console.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your reply. I changed `powershell_ise.exe` to `powershell.exe` but the result remains the same. I edited the question with my updated scripts

Comment: What happens if you just run the `$process = Start-Process powershell.exe` (the whole line until after the args[0]) directly on the remote computer? Not just the `import.ps1` directly. When I start another .ps1 (which starts an IE session) with Start-Process, the Start-Process is only done after I close the IE window, which is what I would expect...

Comment: @DanStef I just found out that my concept ist working. I will edit my question and post the solution if anyone else is interested in this somewhen in the future.